# Is there a way to record data using a Python script through multiple power cycles (Power supplied/cut) without writing over previous data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Developing a python script to use in a Raspberry Pi to record voltage/current data whenever the Pi is powered on. Issues have arisen when files corrupt if they are open when power is cut to the Pi.

Currently, I am using an infinite While loop (While True) to append the voltage/current data to individual text files. I currently have the file open and close within the While loop to try and prevent the files from corrupting when power is cut. By using systemd in the Pi, I am able to run the python script on boot, and it will run until the power is cut or one of the voltage/current sensors is unplugged. I need the system to be able to turn on when power is supplied and record data and properly turn off when power is cut. It should be able to do this cycle infinitely without any issues.

Is there a surefire way to prevent the files from corrupting when power is cut to the Pi without writing over any previous data recorded from other cycles? Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be helpful.

I was considering writing batches to individual files i.e., 1000 data points to VoltageData1.txt, 1000 data points to VoltageData2.txt. But I am unsure how you could prevent each cycle from writing over the previous cycles data when the power is cut and turned back on again.

**UPDATE**
I created a sqlite database to use to record data which runs properly when I run the code outright in a code editor, but when the code tries to run on boot it fails. I am assuming the service needed for the database hasn't loaded before the code tries to run which causes the code service to fail.

Is anyone aware of the service used to load the sqlite database on boot?

Comment: Just use some code to make sure that the filename you're trying to write to doesn't exist.

Comment: Use `file.flush()` and `os.fsync()` after each write to minimize buffering.

Comment: You could include the time of creation in your filename, e.g. `VoltageData_20230523-155100.txt`. Then kind of by definition you avoid a filename clash on restart.

Comment: I would say that there is no perfectly safe way but an sqlite database should be pretty safe as it is designed to handle such cases (atomic and durable commits).